# Is it Possible to Check How Many Times a Remote Process Accesses an Address in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windows-xp, windows-ce

Using the Windows API Debugging functions or any other Windows API functions and assuming full permissions, is it possible to determine whether a process has accessed an address in it's address space?
My ultimate goal is to create a tool that gets the address of a mapped file in memory and determines how many times each part of the file is accessed by the debugee.
My first thought was memory breakpoints, but I'm not sure if I can set those in a remote process or even what commands I would use to set those.

**Edit**

Assembly answers using debug registers are welcome, note that I am using the ARM v4 based Intel XScale. I am aware of DBRCON and DBRx registers, but I'm not sure how to get a remote process to use them.
Efficiency is not a concern, so single stepping through a process and determining how many times an address is accessed is fine, but I'm not sure how I would accomplish this programatically.